# javascript array.slice().push() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, slice

The following code produces (in Chrome javascript console)

a: (3) [1, 2, 3]   b: (4) [1, 2, 3, 99]   c: 4

I expected c to look like b. Why doesn't it?

```
function snafu(){
    var a = [1,2,3];
    var b = a.slice();
    var c = a.slice().push(99);
    b.push(99);
    console.log("a:",a,"  b:",b,"  c:",c);
}
```

Comment: you can replace push with concat and it should work

Answer (score 2):

`Array.push()` gives you value of `Array.length` and not array itself

```js
var a = [];
var b = a.push(8); /* returns length of array after pushing value into array */
console.log('a = ', a, ', b = ', b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, remember `Array.slice()` will return you new Array. So while pushing it on `slice()`, it'll return you length of the array.

```
function snafu(){
    var a = [1,2,3];
    var b = a.slice();
    var c = a.slice();
    c.push(99);
    b.push(99);
    console.log("a:",a,"  b:",b,"  c:",c);
}

snafu();
```

`variable c` will give you new Array so you can do whatever you want with `c`.

That's it. Easy!!!!